What is the equivalent realization of a waveplate in a Stern-Gerlach experiment?
When doing experiments that are equivalent to Stern-Gerlach measurements using photons, we can use polarizing beam splitters and combinations of half- and quarter-waveplates to select over which basis ($H$/$V$, $+$/$-$ or $R$/$L$) we are preparing states and performing measurements. In a classical Stern-Gerlach experiment, the combination of the magnets itself will effectively act like a PBS. I'm wondering what would be the equivalent of a half- or quarter-waveplate in a Stern-Gerlach realization.
For example, I could 1) take an unpolarized light source and pass it through a PBS, and then 2) take one of the outputs (say $|H\rangle$) and pass it through a HWP to rotate it into $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|H\rangle + |V\rangle)$. Finally, I can 3) pass it through an analyzer consisting of a HWP + PBS to verify that it is indeed $|+\rangle$ if it comes out at the right output.
In the SG realization, we could 1) take a thermal beam of atoms and then pass it through a SG device oriented along $\hat{z}$. Then, we take the $|+z\rangle$ beam of the output. However, what can we do to obtain an equivalent step to 2)? We would have to "rotate" the $|+z\rangle$ into $|+x\rangle$, but I'm not sure how to do this experimentally.

Photon's polarization measurement may be the equivalent counterpart of electron's Stern-Gerlach measurement (electron spin and photon polarization can even be entangled together). The electron has another degree of freedom though, helicity, that the photon (and oddly neutrino) does not have.

Turning on a uniform magnetic field where the atoms are should perform the operation you're looking for. The magnetic field does not vary over space, so no net force is applied. This means the beam does not split in two as in the regular Stern-Gerlach.
In particular, a magnetic field in the $y$ direction should rotate spins in the $x\wedge z$ plane, with the amount of rotation being proportional to the strength of the field and the time the atoms spend there. The reason is that the field splits the energy of the $|+y\rangle, |-y\rangle$ states and so the two components pick up a difference in phase over time due to the energy difference.
